# downloading geojson file into folium in jupyter

Tags: pandas, mapping, geojson, jupyter, folium

I want a map of Europe (as json file, so i can work with geojson) to place it on Folium map as layers so I am able to embed my data set onto it to show which country in Europe has the highest alcohol serving. I am having problems with getting the json file from GitHub to open in jyputer

This is what I have so far [image] and i have the file of europe country in geojson from github https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid/blob/master/docs/eu-countries.geo.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to download that file. Now you will be able to add the layer:

```
# geo_path is the path to your geojson file
map1.choropleth(geo_path=geo_path)
display(map1)
```

Comment: if you click onto the GitHub link, the geojson file is actually HTML. Do you know how to extract it in json file?

Comment: Go here https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid. There you will see a green button called "Clone por Download", press it and then press "Download as Zip". Now you will have downloaded a zip file with all the files of the repository and you will be able to get the specific file you want.